# Spring Data Rest 2.0.0 - @RestResource (exported=false) doesn't work for properties

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to avoid showing a couple fields in the content of the JSON response using spring-data-rest. The annotation @RestResource(exported = false) is not working for a property in an Entity class. It could be a similar issue to the one reported in: [Property reference mapping in Spring Data Rest 2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283300/property-reference-mapping-in-spring-data-rest-2-0-0)

In my case I have the next two properties:

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
private byte[] image;
@RestResource(exported = false)
private Date updateTime;
```

The annotation is not working. I also tried the next approach without success:

```
@Override
protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {    
config.setResourceMappingForDomainType(MyClass.class)
                .addResourceMappingFor("updateTime")
                .setExported(false);
}
```

Looking at the spring-data-rest current code in github makes me think that any metadata (annotation) to set the content for the JSON objects is never used. I appreciate your help with this issue. Maybe is there a different way to do it in the current 2.0.0 versions?

Comment: Try using both `@RestResource` and `@JsonIgnore`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latests snapshot the following should work

```
@JsonIgnore
private byte[] image;

@JsonIgnore
private Date updateTime;
```

By the way, @RestResource is a class and method annotation and  is tell SDR if you like to expose those classes or methods through SDR

For controlling serialization of domain object use jackson annotation @JsonIgnore

Answer (score 1):

It should be fixed in the next release as this [issue report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-87) says.